# Non-default IPython profile in Spyder console

Tags: ipython, spyder

I use two installations of Spyder, one using my default python 2.7 and the other running in a python 3.4 virtualenv. However, the history of the IPython console is shared between the two. The cleanest way to have separate histories would be to define a new IPython profile for the python 3.4 installation. My question is: how to convince Spyder to run IPython with a non-default profile? I could not find any way to supply command line options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Carlos' answer, there is no way to start an IPython console inside Spyder with a different profile. A workaround is to duplicate the ~/.ipython directory (I named mine ~/.ipython3) and set the environment variable IPYTHONDIR to the new location before running the python 3 version of Spyder. It will then use the profile_default in the new directory.

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder dev here*) There is no way to start an IPython console inside Spyder with a different profile. We use the default profile to create all our consoles.